# I am sending a long paragraph to mysql via flutter but the paragraph is not getting inserted in the database

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart

this is the php api code

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';
$about = $_GET['about'];
$connect -> query("INSERT INTO abouts(about) VALUES('".$about."')");
?>
```

this is the dart code

```
http.Response response = await http.get("api.php?about="+aboutTextEditingController.text);
```

lorem ipsum is the text I am inserting via text field

Comment: GET has a length limit of approx 2048 chars - is it possible the `sentence` exceeds that?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Post error details or debug information so it will help others to easily understand the problem and post solution.

But you can check -
- MySQL column type and it's length

Post MySQL error if possible.

Comment: As @RamRaider said you are probably hitting the character limit for a GET request. You should use a POST request instead (it's good practice to use a POST request when creating an entity anyway)

Comment: post request is also not working. there's no error.. when the paragraph is smaller the data gets inserted.. but when the paragraph is long the data isn't inserted

Comment: Is the field in your table text or varchar, it should be text.

Comment: the datatype is longtext